# The best way to organize the files in a large ASP.NET MVC2 project?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, project

I've looked all over the web for the best way to organize an ASP.NET MVC2 project.  I've only seen examples of people using the default template for MVC2 projects.  But is this the best way to organize your project if it is going to contain a large number of files?

We're in the process of building an application that is heavily built around jQuery for UI and ajax using JSON.  So, as you can imagine, we will have many custom .js support scripts.

In our solution, we have placed all our support libraries (3rd party and custom) into respective projects.  The MVC2 project that is also in the solution is using the default MVC2 template.

In the MVC2 project, the "starting" structure is still pretty much unchanged.  Under the Controllers directory, we have each controller AccountController.cs and HomeController.cs (for example).  Under the Views directory, we have three subdirectories named Account, Home, and Shared.  In the Scripts, directory we have also divided that up with three directories, Account, Home, and Shared. And finally we have the Models directory, that is also divided into Account, Home, and Shared subdirectories.

As you can see we haven't deviated from the basic template that much.  But, as we start adding stuff to this, we're realizing how cumbersome this might become when we get upwards to 20 or 30 views and 100 support .js files.

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into using Areas to organize your Views/Controllers/Models/Content.

Here's a good article from Microsoft: [Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> To accommodate large projects, ASP.NET MVC lets you partition Web applications into smaller units that are referred to as areas. Areas provide a way to separate a large MVC Web application into smaller functional groupings. An area is effectively an MVC structure inside an application. An application could contain several MVC structures (areas).

Comment: Hey thanks for this.  I'm looking into this. Wonder why a MVC2 project just isn't setup like this from the beginning?  Also, is seems it adds a web.config file for each Area/View.  Is this web.config file necessary for each area?

Comment: I think most people aren't even aware of them unless you get to the point where you are at as far as looking for better organization. Yes, the web.configs are necessary per Area.

Comment: Well, I've been messing with them for the last 30 mins and already see how this is far superior.  Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: So, in Area organization, where do you place Global views for items like AccessDenied.aspx and/or LoginRequest.aspx that don't really belong to any specific area?

Comment: For things like that I usually put them in `~/Views/Shared/*` and create a `~/Controllers/SharedController.cs`